# 10GBit Ethernet network mesh switch with brouting and "VLAN"

Tags: routing, ethernet, bridge, load-balancing, vlan

I want to create a mesh network with 10GBit Ethernet links between servers and a switch stack capable of distributed trunking.

In this scenario for a number *n>2* (but typically *2<n<6*) imagine:

- 1 Switch stack with at least *n* physical members, capable of distributed trunking on 10GB links.
- *n* hosts, each with

  - *n+1* 10GB interfaces, of those using

    - *n-1* for connecting directly to all other *n-1* hosts to create the physical full mesh between the servers. Example pictures below
    - 2 connections in one `bond0` to the switch stack, to different members.
- *k* number of VLANs

GraphViz PNG rendering<sup>(1)</sup> of fully meshed server node constellation with n=5:

<kbd><kbd>`/*_5_Server_Nodes_Network_Mesh_°°°*/ graph n5 {
node[shape=plaintext,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
edge[len=0.6]
  a-- b-- c-- d-- e-- a-- c-- e-- b-- d-- a
}`</kbd>[image: 5 Node Server Mesh]</kbd>

Note: To keep the graphs small, I chose *n=3* and *k=2* for the rest of this question, because 3 Nodes in a triangle formation are fully meshed, and the same solution should apply.

<kbd><kbd>`/*_3_Server_Nodes_Network_Mesh_°°°*/ graph n3 {
node[shape=plaintext,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
edge[len=0.4]
a -- b -- c -- a }`</kbd>
[image: 3 Node Mesh Network]</kbd>

<sub>Lets say, the cards used for these connection are `eth0`&`eth1` ({0..(n-2)})</sub>

I also need to be establish `k` zones, VLANs(blue). Say VLANs *M*, and *N*:

<kbd><kbd>`/*_3_Server_Mesh_with_VLAN__°°°°°°*/ graph n3 {
node[shape=plaintext,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
edge[len=0.4]
  a -- b -- c -- a
edge[color=blue]
  a--{aM aN}; b--{bM bN}; c--{cM cN};
}`</kbd>[image]</kbd>

2 more of the 10GBit Ethernet Ports (here `eth2`&`eth3`) on each hosts are bonded(brown) for upstream connection to outside world:

<kbd><kbd>`/*_3_Server_Mesh_w/_VLAN_and_bond0__*/ graph n3 {
node[shape=plaintext,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
edge[len=0.3]; a -- b -- c -- a
edge[color=blue]
  a--{aM aN}; b--{bM bN}; c--{cM cN};
edge[color=brown,len=0.4,penwidth=2]
  a -- au; b -- bu; c -- cu;}`</kbd>
[image: 3_Server_Mesh_w/_VLAN_and_bond0]</kbd>

Both ports of the `bond0` interface to the different members of the upstream switch stack, that itself uses a ring of 10GBit connections(green) for stacking:

<kbd><kbd>`/*_3_Servers_w/VLAN+Stack*/ graph n3 {
node[shape=plaintext,margin=0,
     height=0,width=0]
edge[len=0.3]
  a -- b -- c -- a
edge[color=blue,len=0.3]
  a--{aM aX}; b--{bM bN}; c--{cM cN};
edge[color=brown,len=0.4]
  a -- au; b -- bu; c -- cu;
edge[color=brown,len=1.1]
  {cu[shape=point] au} -- S1
  {au[shape=point] bu} -- S2
  {bu[shape=point] cu} -- S3
edge[color=green,len=2.9]
  S1 -- S2 -- S3 --S1 }`</kbd>
[image: 3_Servers_w/_VLAN_and_Stack]</kbd>

And all the users would would be connected to (networks on) the "outside" of *S1..S$n*

Logically, the Switch stack *S1..S$n* behaves like one big Switching Unit. So, the servers *a,b,..,n* see the following structure, with everything else connected to *S*

<kbd><kbd>`/*_3_Server_Mesh_w/_VLAN_and_Stack__*/ graph n3 {
node[shape=plaintext,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
edge[len=1]; a -- b -- c -- a
edge[color=brown,len=0.3,penwidth=2]
S -- {a b c}
edge[color=blue,len=0.3]
a--{aM aN}; b--{bM bN}; c--{cM cN};
}`</kbd>
[image]</kbd>

Now we connect some Virtual Machines(red) to these VLANs:

<kbd><kbd>`/*_3_Server_Mesh_with_VLAN_clients__*/ graph n3 {
node[shape=plaintext,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
edge[len=1]; a -- b -- c -- a
edge[color=brown,len=0.3,penwidth=2]
  S -- {a b c}
edge[color=blue,len=0.3,penwidth=1]
  a--{aM aN}; b--{bM bN}; c--{cM cN};
edge[color=red,len=0.3,penwidth=1]
  v1--{aM aN}; {v2 v7}--bM; v3--{cM cN};
  v4--aN; {v5 v6 v8}--bN; v9--cM;
}`</kbd>
[image: 3_Server_Mesh_with_VLAN_clients]</kbd>

This is the sort of functionality often seen in context with SDN, SPB, TRILL, VxLAN, all of which seem relevant after checking them out.
Of those [Shortest Path Bridging(802.1aq)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1aq) sounds like the best fit.
But where are the implementations for linux, and how do I use them on Debian to build a fully meshed brouter?

- [SPB - Shortest Path Bridging(802.1aq)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1aq)  sounds like a winner: Official replacement for Spanning Tree, since 2012. [There seems to be ongoing project on Github](https://github.com/openss7/pbbr), not sure, if complete/functional
- [TRILL - Transparent Interconnection of Lots of Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRILL_%28computing%29): Major competitor to SPB. [Github Project](https://github.com/VirtuOR/OpenTRILL), also does not seem available/functional
- [OpenMesh batman-adv](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/batman-adv/wiki/Wiki). It's available in Debian. But everywhere I read about it is about *wireless*. If it would work for 10GBit links, wouldn't everybody use that? (And there'd be online chat about it)
- [VDE Virtual Switch](http://wiki.virtualsquare.org/wiki/index.php/VDE_Basic_Networking). Also available in Debian. Entirely in userspace, therefore too slow for 10GBit/s?
- @JuliePelletier in a comment suggested BGP as the means to achieve this brouted,fault-tolerant Layer2 setup, but I cannot yet see how exactly she meant that.

So what could I install/configure on each node to achieve the desired constellation?

<sub>(1) `Graphviz` renderings were created with
`neato -Tpng -O file.dot && browser file.dot.png`</sub>

Comment: Can't you simply install BGP on each node so that they can share their routing information?

Comment: That's one unusual network. Unless you have highly special requirements (which you did not include in the question) I strongly suggest you talk to a network engineer.

Comment: @AlexP: Unusual? The above is just a formal description of a fully meshed network illustrated for the simplest case, a triangle formation. This mesh uses 10G connections for meshing, and another 2 per host to connect to "a big external switch". This is a fairly easy setup. I have setup such networks. This question is about avoiding the shortcomings of STP, as mentioned. The official successor is SPB. A competing standard is TRILL. I want to get one of them to work. But I would also accept something with the same gains as sought with SPB/TRILL.

Comment: ~2.5h before the end of the bounty somebody started a [thread on the B.A.T.M.A.N. mailing list](https://lists.open-mesh.org/pipermail/b.a.t.m.a.n/2016-December/016751.html) asking for precisely this scenario :)